# What are the different log files in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB I have several log files in the repository/log directory. What are the differences and which one should I use for the daily control if everything is alright?

Here the list of log files:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I experienced now the following:

- **http_access_xxxx.log**: Contains log of any HTTP access (in my case only the carbon admin jsp)
- **wso2carbon.log**: Contains the real log output of the Application Server (most important one)
- **wso2carbon-trace-messages.log**: Always empty - don't know what it is for
- **wso2-esb-error.log**: Lists all WARNING and ERROR message from the wso2carbon.log again here - no INFO or DEBUG messages
- **wso2-esb-service.log**: Contains all logs that have been made with the "Log" Mediator in Synapse Proxies or Sequences
- **wso2-esb-trace.log**: Always empty - don't know what it is for

Well just add your monitoring on the **wso2carbon.log** file and you have everything essential.

Comment: To know more information about wso2-esb-trace.log see the next post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936119/trace-log-file-in-wso2-esb/31937803#31937803

Answer (score 2):

WSO2carbon.log contains most of the logs about the server (service logs , error logs etc.) You can use it as the main log for maintaining. http_acces log contain about Apache access logs. Serivce logs have individual ESB services logs.

Comment: Ok but as it seems to be the most important file, you may answer my other question why the that file is not kept longer than 24 hours. It always get erased by midnight...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758378/wso2-esb-backup-also-the-wso2carbon-log-file-over-several-days