# WSO2 ESB: Backup also the wso2carbon.log file over several days?

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB 4.5.1 has [several log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758323/what-are-the-different-log-files-in-wso2-esb) in the repository/logs folder. But an important "wso2carbon.log" is only containing the whole log of one day. Then at midnight it is flushed.
Because other log files in the same directory (wso2-esb-service.log or http_access.log) have this feature are being kept a couple of days.

How can I keep the wso2carbon.log files also for some days? (WSO2 should just rename them, not delete them).

Here my log4j.properties in the conf directory:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, CARBON_CONSOLE, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY, CARBON_SYS_LOG, ERROR_LOGFILE

log4j.category.org.apache.synapse=INFO
log4j.category.org.apache.synapse.transport=INFO
log4j.category.org.apache.axis2=INFO
log4j.category.org.apache.axis2.transport=INFO
log4j.logger.com.atomikos=INFO,ATOMIKOS
log4j.logger.org.quartz=WARN
log4j.logger.org.wso2=INFO
log4j.logger.com.avintis=INFO
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon=INFO
#log4j.category.org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util=DEBUG
#log4j.category.org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.utils.deployment.ComponentBuilder=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.utils.deployment.OSGiBundleDeployer=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.coyote=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.enterprise=FATAL
log4j.logger.de.hunsicker.jalopy.io=FATAL

# uncomment the following logs to see HTTP headers and messages
#log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.headers=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.wire=DEBUG

# qpid related logs for the message broker
log4j.logger.qpid=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.qpid=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.qpid.server.Main=INFO
log4j.logger.qpid.message=WARN
log4j.logger.qpid.message.broker.listening=INFO

# The console appender is used to display general information at console
log4j.appender.CARBON_CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CARBON_CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CARBON_CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}] %5p - %c{1} %m%n

# LOGEVENT is set to be a LogEventAppender using a PatternLayout to send logs to LOGEVENT 
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT=org.wso2.carbon.logging.appender.LogEventAppender
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.url=tcp://localhost:7611
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.columnList=%T,%S,%A,%d,%c,%p,%m,%I,%Stacktrace
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.userName=admin
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.password=admin
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.processingLimit=1000
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.maxTolerableConsecutiveFailure=20

# Configure the service logger at INFO level. Writes only run-time/mediation-time audit messages
log4j.category.SERVICE_LOGGER=INFO, SERVICE_APPENDER
log4j.additivity.SERVICE_LOGGER=false
log4j.appender.SERVICE_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SERVICE_APPENDER.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/${instance.log}/wso2-esb-service${instance.log}.log
log4j.appender.SERVICE_APPENDER.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.SERVICE_APPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.SERVICE_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SERVICE_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%X{ip}-%X{host}] [%t] %5p %c{1} %m%n

# The trace logger dumps enough information @INFO level, but maybe pushed upto TRACE.
# Writes only run-time/mediation time tracing/debug messages for messages passing through trace
# enabled sequences, mediators and services. Enabling tracing on these has a performance impact
log4j.category.TRACE_LOGGER=INFO, TRACE_APPENDER, TRACE_MEMORYAPPENDER
log4j.additivity.TRACE_LOGGER=false
log4j.appender.TRACE_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.TRACE_APPENDER.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/${instance.log}/wso2-esb-trace${instance.log}.log
log4j.appender.TRACE_APPENDER.Append=true
log4j.appender.TRACE_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TRACE_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%X{ip}-%X{host}] [%t] %5p %c{1} %m%n

# The memory appender for trace logger
log4j.appender.TRACE_MEMORYAPPENDER=org.wso2.carbon.logging.appenders.MemoryAppender
log4j.appender.TRACE_MEMORYAPPENDER.bufferSize=2000
log4j.appender.TRACE_MEMORYAPPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TRACE_MEMORYAPPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%X{ip}-%X{host}] [%t] %5p %m%n

# CARBON_LOGFILE is set to be a DailyRollingFileAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
# Log file will be overridden by the configuration setting in the DB
# This path should be relative to WSO2 Carbon Home
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/${instance.log}/wso2carbon${instance.log}.log
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
# ConversionPattern will be overridden by the configuration setting in the DB
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=TID: [%T] [%S] [%d] %P%5p {%c} - %x %m {%c}%n
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.layout.TenantPattern=%U%@%D [%T] [%S]
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.threshold=DEBUG

# The standard error log where all the warnings, errors and fatal errors will be logged
log4j.appender.ERROR_LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.ERROR_LOGFILE.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/${instance.log}/wso2-esb-errors.log
log4j.appender.ERROR_LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ERROR_LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%X{ip}-%X{host}] [%t] %5p %c{1} %m%n
log4j.appender.ERROR_LOGFILE.threshold=WARN

# The memory appender for logging
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY=org.wso2.carbon.logging.appender.CarbonMemoryAppender
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.bufferSize=2000
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
# ConversionPattern will be overridden by the configuration setting in the DB
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.layout.ConversionPattern=TID: [%T] [%S] [%d] %P%5p {%c} - %x %m {%c}%n
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.layout.TenantPattern=%U%@%D [%T] [%S]
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.columnList=%T,%S,%A,%d,%c,%p,%m,%H,%I,%Stacktrace
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.threshold=DEBUG

log4j.appender.CARBON_SYS_LOG = org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.CARBON_SYS_LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CARBON_SYS_LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %5p - %x %m {%c}%n
log4j.appender.CARBON_SYS_LOG.SyslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.CARBON_SYS_LOG.Facility=USER
log4j.appender.CARBON_SYS_LOG.threshold=DEBUG

log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.shared.ldap=WARN, CARBON_CONSOLE
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers=WARN, CARBON_CONSOLE
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.entry.DefaultServerAttribute=FATAL, CARBON_CONSOLE
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.ldif.LdifReader=ERROR, CARBON_CONSOLE
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapProtocolHandler=ERROR, CARBON_CONSOLE

## Trace Logger configuration which will append to a XMPP chatroom or JID ##
#log4j.appender.XMPP_APPENDER=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.IMAppender
#log4j.appender.XMPP_APPENDER.host=jabber.org
#log4j.appender.XMPP_APPENDER.username=wso2esb
#log4j.appender.XMPP_APPENDER.password=wso2esb
#log4j.appender.XMPP_APPENDER.recipient=ruwan@jabber.org
#log4j.appender.XMPP_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.XMPP_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=[%X{host}] [%t] %-5p [%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %C{1} - %m%n

# Appender config to send Atomikos transaction logs to new log file tm.out.
log4j.appender.ATOMIKOS = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ATOMIKOS.File = repository/logs/tm.out
log4j.appender.ATOMIKOS.Append = true
log4j.appender.ATOMIKOS.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ATOMIKOS.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.additivity.com.atomikos=false
```

Comment: Have you changed anything at log4j.properties in repository/conf? usually they are there with filenames like wso2carbon.log.2012-11-29

Comment: I just added a new log namespace. But already before it was not the case. I edit the question and add the log4j contig...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You configuration looks ok and it should rotate your log file end of each day. If you are a windows user there was a rotating issue reported[1]. This has been fixed in the latest carbon packs

[1]- https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1614

Comment: Ok good to know: WSO2 ESB 4.5.0, 4.5.1 and 4.6.0 have this issue with Windows. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the "DailyRollingFileAppender" which rolls logs daily and keep it inside the same folder with the naming pattern "wso2carbon.yyy-mm-dd.log". I believe this is the option which is by default attached as the appender of the wso2carbon.log file in the log4j configuration of any Carbon product including WSO2 ESB.

Comment: I use the default configuration with DailyRollingFileAppender, but there is no backup done at all. At midnight is erased. Can you have a look at my configuration - what's missing there?

Answer (score 0):

I've created my own backup of the files using a task that runs at 23:59 each day. Well I'll lose one minute of log, but that's better than loosing the whole file.