# Trace log file in WSO2 ESB

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB, What does it show exactly the wso2-esb-trace.log file?, When might it be useful?

And, What the different with other typical logs files in WSO2 ESB? For example, with wso2-esb-service.log or wso2-esb-error.log

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the different log files in WSO2 ESB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758323/what-are-the-different-log-files-in-wso2-esb)

Comment: In that article, the author doesn't know what info appear in wso2-esb-trace.log. I need to know exactly this info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It offers you a way to monitor a mediation execution : go to the web console, enable tracing on a sequence or a proxy service, execute this mediation (send a message to the proxy for exemple) and look at "mediation tracer" or edit wso2-esb-trace.log to gain details about it's execution (mediatiors that have been called, evaluation of xpath expressions, ...)

Comment: Thanks, it is very useful for me. And, Do you know the differences between wso2-esb-trace.log and wso2carbon-trace-message.log files?

Comment: In ESB_HOME/lib, you can find a jar named "org.wso2.carbon.server-4.2.0.jar" containing a default log4j.properties conf which define a CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE appender associated to a file named wso2carbon-trace-message.log. The only logger refering to this appender is "trace.messages" and I can't find it anyware in java source code so I guess that this file will always be empty in wso2 ESB